# How do I use the same js function to display two carousels

Tags: javascript, html, slider, carousel

I have a carousel slider on my website and I duplicated it to have another similar slider on the same page. The first carousel works fine but in the second one previous and next buttons don't work and not all slides are showing. Is there a way to re-use the same function twice on the same page? Or there is something else going on here? Anything will help.

Here is my code for two carousels:

```
<article class="content menu-top dark">
    <section class="featured-slider">
            <div class="ca-container">
                <div class="nav-featured">
                    <div class="prev-featured"></div>
                    <a href="#anchor3"><div class="btn-featured">Button</div></a>
                    <div class="next-featured"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="main-carousel hideme dontHide">
                    <div class="ca-wrapper">
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
                            <div class="f-single">
                                <a href="#" class="mfp-iframe">
                                    <div class="f-image">
                                        <img src="image1.jpg" alt='img'>
                                        <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                                        <span class="f-category"></span>
                                        <div class="portfolio-meta">
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <div>Watch Now</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="f-info">Text</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-2">
                            <div class="f-single">
                                <a href="#" class="mfp-iframe">
                                    <div class="f-image">
                                        <img src="image2.jpg" alt='img'>
                                        <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                                        <span class="f-category"></span>
                                        <div class="portfolio-meta">
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <div>Watch Now</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="f-info">Text</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-3">
                            <div class="f-single">
                                <a href="#" class="mfp-iframe">
                                    <div class="f-image">
                                        <img src="image3.jpg" alt='img'>
                                        <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                                        <span class="f-category"></span>
                                        <div class="portfolio-meta">
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <div>Watch Now</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="f-info">Text</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-4">
                            <div class="f-single">
                                <a href="#" class="mfp-iframe">
                                    <div class="f-image">
                                        <img src="image4.jpg" alt='img'>
                                        <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                                        <span class="f-category"></span>
                                        <div class="portfolio-meta">
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <div>Watch Now</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="f-info">Text</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-5">
                            <div class="f-single">
                                <a href="#" class="mfp-iframe">
                                    <div class="f-image">
                                        <img src="image5.jpg" alt='img'>
                                        <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                                        <span class="f-category"></span>
                                        <div class="portfolio-meta">
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <div>Watch Now</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="f-info">Text</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="ca-item ca-item-6">
                            <div class="f-single">
                                <a href="#" class="mfp-iframe">
                                    <div class="f-image">
                                        <img src="image6.jpg" alt='img'>
                                        <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                                        <span class="f-category"></span>
                                        <div class="portfolio-meta">
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <div>Watch Now</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="f-info">Text</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </article>



    <article class="content menu-top dark">
        <section class="featured-slider">
            <div class="ca-container">
                <div class="nav-featured">
                    <div class="prev-featured"></div>
                    <a href="#anchor5"><div class="btn-featured">Button</div></a>
                    <div class="next-featured"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="main-carousel hideme dontHide">
                    <div class="ca-wrapper">
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
                            <div class="f-single">
                                <a href="image7.jpg">
                                    <div class="f-image">
                                        <img src="image8.jpg" alt='img'>
                                        <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                                        <span class="f-category"></span>
                                        <div class="portfolio-meta">
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="f-info">Text</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-2">
                            <div class="f-single">
                                <a href="image9.jpg">
                                    <div class="f-image">
                                        <img src="image10.jpg" alt='img'>
                                        <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                                        <span class="f-category"></span>
                                        <div class="portfolio-meta">
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="f-info">Text</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-3">
                            <div class="f-single">
                                <a href="image11.jpg">
                                    <div class="f-image">
                                        <img src="image12.jpg" alt='img'>
                                        <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                                        <span class="f-category"></span>
                                        <div class="portfolio-meta">
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="f-info">Text</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-4">
                            <div class="f-single">
                                <a href="image13.jpg">
                                    <div class="f-image">
                                        <img src="image14.jpg" alt='img'>
                                        <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                                        <span class="f-category"></span>
                                        <div class="portfolio-meta">
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="f-info">Text</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-5">
                            <div class="f-single">
                                <a href="image15.jpg">
                                    <div class="f-image">
                                        <img src="image16.jpg" alt='img'>
                                        <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                                        <span class="f-category"></span>
                                        <div class="portfolio-meta">
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="f-info">Text</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-6">
                            <div class="f-single">
                                <a href="image17.jpg">
                                    <div class="f-image">
                                        <img src="image18.jpg" alt='img'>
                                        <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                                        <span class="f-category"></span>
                                        <div class="portfolio-meta">
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="f-info">Wales</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-7">
                            <div class="f-single">
                                <a href="image19.jpg">
                                    <div class="f-image">
                                        <img src="image20.jpg" alt='img'>
                                        <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                                        <span class="f-category"></span>
                                        <div class="portfolio-meta">
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="f-info">Text</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-item ca-item-8">
                            <div class="f-single">
                                <a href="image21.jpg">
                                    <div class="f-image">
                                        <img src="image22.jpg" alt='img'>
                                        <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                                        <span class="f-category"></span>
                                        <div class="portfolio-meta">
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <div>Text</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="f-info">Text</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </article>
```

JS for the carousels:

```
(function($) {var   aux     = {
        navigate    : function( dir, $el, $wrapper, opts, cache ) {

            var scroll      = opts.scroll,
                factor      = 1,
                idxClicked  = 0;

            if( cache.expanded ) {
                scroll      = 1; // scroll is always 1 in full mode
                factor      = 3; // the width of the expanded item will be 3 times bigger than 1 collapsed item
                idxClicked  = cache.idxClicked; // the index of the clicked item
            }

            // clone the elements on the right / left and append / prepend them according to dir and scroll
            if( dir === 1 ) {
                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:lt(' + scroll + ')').each(function(i) {
                    $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', ( cache.totalItems - idxClicked + i ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).appendTo( $wrapper );
                });
            }
            else {
                var $first  = $wrapper.children().eq(0);

                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:gt(' + ( cache.totalItems  - 1 - scroll ) + ')').each(function(i) {
                    // insert before $first so they stay in the right order
                    $(this).clone(true).css( 'left', - ( scroll - i + idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px' ).insertBefore( $first );
                });
            }

            // animate the left of each item
            // the calculations are dependent on dir and on the cache.expanded value
            $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {

                var $item   = $(this);
                $item.stop().animate({
                    left    :  ( dir === 1 ) ? '-=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px' : '+=' + ( cache.itemW * factor * scroll ) + 'px'
                }, opts.sliderSpeed, opts.sliderEasing, function() {
                    if( ( dir === 1 && $item.position().left < - idxClicked * cache.itemW * factor ) || ( dir === -1 && $item.position().left > ( ( cache.totalItems - 1 - idxClicked ) * cache.itemW * factor ) ) ) {
                        // remove the item that was cloned
                        $item.remove();
                    }
                    cache.isAnimating   = false;
                });
            });
        },
        // gets the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items)
        // val is the left of the item
        getWinPos   : function( val, cache ) {
            switch( val ) {
                case 0                  : return 1; break;
                case cache.itemW        : return 2; break;
                case cache.itemW * 2    : return 3; break;
            }
        }
    },
    methods = {
        init        : function( options ) {

            if( this.length ) {

                var settings = {
                    sliderSpeed     : 500,          // speed for the sliding animation
                    sliderEasing    : 'easeInOutCubic',// easing for the sliding animation
                    scroll          : 1             // number of items to scroll at a time
                };

                return this.each(function() {

                    // if options exist, lets merge them with our default settings
                    if ( options ) {
                        $.extend( settings, options );
                    }

                    var $el             = $(this),
                        $wrapper        = $el.find('div.ca-wrapper'),
                        $items          = $wrapper.children('div.ca-item'),
                        cache           = {};

                    // save the with of one item
                    cache.itemW         = $items.width();
                    // save the number of total items
                    cache.totalItems    = $items.length;

                    //centrar
                    $('.ca-wrapper').css('margin-left',-(cache.totalItems*cache.itemW/2))

                    // control the scroll value
                    if( settings.scroll < 1 )
                        settings.scroll = 1;
                    else if( settings.scroll > 3 )
                        settings.scroll = 3;

                    var $navPrev        = $el.find('.prev-featured'),
                        $navNext        = $el.find('.next-featured');

                    // hide the items except the first 3
                    //$wrapper.css( 'overflow', 'hidden' );

                    // the items will have position absolute
                    // calculate the left of each item
                    $items.each(function(i) {
                        $(this).css({
                            position    : 'absolute',
                            left        : i * cache.itemW + 'px'
                        });
                        //if(i==2){$('.f-single',this).addClass('active')}else{$('.f-single',this).removeClass('active')}
                    });

                    // navigate left
                    $navPrev.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                    });

                    // navigate right
                    $navNext.bind('click.contentcarousel', function( event ) {
                        if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                        cache.isAnimating   = true;
                        aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    };
$.fn.contentcarousel = function(method) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.contentcarousel' );
    }
};
})(jQuery);
```

CSS:

```
.main-carousel{
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
height:376px;
}
.f-image{
color: #fff;
}
.f-image a{
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
.f-single .portfolio-meta,.t-element .portfolio-meta {
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 20;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.f-single .portfolio-meta,.t-element .portfolio-meta {
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 20;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}


.f-single:hover .portfolio-meta,.t-element:hover .portfolio-meta{
bottom: 75px;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.f-single:hover .f-category,.t-element:hover .f-category{
top: 85px;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.f-image .f-category{
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 50%;
z-index: 20;
display: block;
margin-left: -22px;
width: 44px;
height: 44px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 44px;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
background: url("color/img/color-icons.png") no-repeat;

-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.f-single a{text-decoration: none;}
.image-hover-overlay {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
}
.f-image .image-hover-overlay,.t-photo .image-hover-overlay {
z-index: 11;
background-color: #000!important;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.f-single:hover .image-hover-overlay,.t-element:hover .image-hover-overlay 
{
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=85);
opacity: .85;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.active .f-info {opacity: 1;}

.ca-container{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.ca-nav span {
width: 25px;
height: 38px;
background: transparent url(../img/f-next.png) no-repeat top left;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -19px;
left: -40px;
text-indent: -9000px;
opacity: 0.7;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 100;
}
.ca-nav span.ca-nav-next {
background-position: top right;
left: auto;
right: -40px;
}
.ca-wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
}
.ca-item{
position: relative;
float: left;
width: auto;
text-align: center;
}

.content{position: relative;}
.dark{background: #282828; padding-bottom: 85px;}

.f-single{
width: 467px;
float: left;
margin: 0 15px;
position: relative;
}
 .f-single:hover .f-image{
opacity: 1;
 }

.f-single:hover .f-info{
cursor: pointer;
opacity: 1;
background: #FF2C2C;
color: #fff;

-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}


.featured-carousel{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
.featured-list{overflow: auto;}
.nav-featured{
margin: 80px auto;
height: 57px;
width: 455px;
}
.nav-featured div{float: left; cursor: pointer;}
 .nav-featured .details-button {
margin-left:37%;
}

.prev-featured{
background: url("../img/f-prev.png") no-repeat #e1e1e1;
width: 30px;
height: 57px;
margin-right: 110px;
}
.prev-featured:hover{background-color: #000000;}
.next-featured{
background: url("../img/f-next.png") no-repeat #e1e1e1;
width: 30px;
height: 57px;
margin-left: 110px;
}
.next-featured:hover{background-color: #000000;}

.nav-featured .btn-featured{
color: #fff;
margin-top: 4px;
font-size: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 400;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
background: #FF2C2C;
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 13px 25px 13px;
letter-spacing: 1px;

-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.nav-featured .btn-featured:hover{background: #000000;}
.btn-featured a{text-decoration: none; color: #fff;}

.title.one{ 
 color: #fff; 
 font-size: 37px; 
 letter-spacing: 5px; 
 padding: 120px 0 30px; 
 text-transform: uppercase;}
.title.two{color: #fff; font-size: 17px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans- 
serif; width: 680px; margin: 50px auto;}
.f-info{
font-weight: 400;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
color: #ffffff;
background: #000000;
line-height: 30px;
padding: 40px 20px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.f-image{
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;

-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.light{background: #000; position: relative;}
.dark:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 30px solid #f7f7f7;
border-bottom: 0px solid transparent !important;
border-right: 30px solid transparent !important;
border-left: 30px solid transparent !important;
left: 50%;
bottom: -28px;
margin-left: -29px;
z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo error here:  <divclass="ca-container">, must be  <div class="ca-container">

Comment: can you provide the css that you use for this plugin ? or it works without adding a css file ?

Comment: how did you use the plugin after defining it in the Js file ? because it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

both carousels worked for me i just had to change position of controls (prev and next with css) because they were overlapping.

```js
(function($) {
  var aux = {
      navigate: function(dir, $el, $wrapper, opts, cache) {

        var scroll = opts.scroll,
          factor = 1,
          idxClicked = 0;

        if (cache.expanded) {
          scroll = 1; // scroll is always 1 in full mode
          factor = 3; // the width of the expanded item will be 3 times bigger than 1 collapsed item
          idxClicked = cache.idxClicked; // the index of the clicked item
        }

        // clone the elements on the right / left and append / prepend them according to dir and scroll
        if (dir === 1) {
          $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:lt(' + scroll + ')').each(function(i) {
            $(this).clone(true).css('left', (cache.totalItems - idxClicked + i) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px').appendTo($wrapper);
          });
        } else {
          var $first = $wrapper.children().eq(0);

          $wrapper.find('div.ca-item:gt(' + (cache.totalItems - 1 - scroll) + ')').each(function(i) {
            // insert before $first so they stay in the right order
            $(this).clone(true).css('left', -(scroll - i + idxClicked) * cache.itemW * factor + 'px').insertBefore($first);
          });
        }

        // animate the left of each item
        // the calculations are dependent on dir and on the cache.expanded value
        $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').each(function(i) {

          var $item = $(this);
          $item.stop().animate({
            left: (dir === 1) ? '-=' + (cache.itemW * factor * scroll) + 'px' : '+=' + (cache.itemW * factor * scroll) + 'px'
          }, opts.sliderSpeed, opts.sliderEasing, function() {
            if ((dir === 1 && $item.position().left < -idxClicked * cache.itemW * factor) || (dir === -1 && $item.position().left > ((cache.totalItems - 1 - idxClicked) * cache.itemW * factor))) {
              // remove the item that was cloned
              $item.remove();
            }
            cache.isAnimating = false;
          });
        });
      },
      // gets the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items)
      // val is the left of the item
      getWinPos: function(val, cache) {
        switch (val) {
          case 0:
            return 1;
            break;
          case cache.itemW:
            return 2;
            break;
          case cache.itemW * 2:
            return 3;
            break;
        }
      }
    },
    methods = {
      init: function(options) {

        if (this.length) {

          var settings = {
            sliderSpeed: 500, // speed for the sliding animation
            sliderEasing: 'easeInOutCubic', // easing for the sliding animation
            scroll: 1 // number of items to scroll at a time
          };

          return this.each(function() {

            // if options exist, lets merge them with our default settings
            if (options) {
              $.extend(settings, options);
            }

            var $el = $(this),
              $wrapper = $el.find('div.ca-wrapper'),
              $items = $wrapper.children('div.ca-item'),
              cache = {};

            // save the with of one item
            cache.itemW = $items.width();
            // save the number of total items
            cache.totalItems = $items.length;

            //centrar
            $('.ca-wrapper').css('margin-left', -(cache.totalItems * cache.itemW / 2))

            // control the scroll value
            if (settings.scroll < 1)
              settings.scroll = 1;
            else if (settings.scroll > 3)
              settings.scroll = 3;

            var $navPrev = $el.find('.prev-featured'),
              $navNext = $el.find('.next-featured');

            // hide the items except the first 3
            //$wrapper.css( 'overflow', 'hidden' );

            // the items will have position absolute
            // calculate the left of each item
            $items.each(function(i) {
              $(this).css({
                position: 'absolute',
                left: i * cache.itemW + 'px'
              });
              //if(i==2){$('.f-single',this).addClass('active')}else{$('.f-single',this).removeClass('active')}
            });

            // navigate left
            $navPrev.bind('click.contentcarousel', function(event) {
              if (cache.isAnimating) return false;
              cache.isAnimating = true;
              aux.navigate(-1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache);
            });

            // navigate right
            $navNext.bind('click.contentcarousel', function(event) {
              if (cache.isAnimating) return false;
              cache.isAnimating = true;
              aux.navigate(1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache);
            });
          });
        }
      }
    };
  $.fn.contentcarousel = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.contentcarousel');
    }
  };
})(jQuery);

//use your plugin on both carousels
$(".featured-slider").contentcarousel({
  sliderEasing: "swing"
});
```

```css
.main-carousel{
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
height:376px;
}
.f-image{
color: #fff;
}
.f-image a{
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
.f-single .portfolio-meta,.t-element .portfolio-meta {
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 20;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.f-single .portfolio-meta,.t-element .portfolio-meta {
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 20;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}


.f-single:hover .portfolio-meta,.t-element:hover .portfolio-meta{
bottom: 75px;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.f-single:hover .f-category,.t-element:hover .f-category{
top: 85px;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.f-image .f-category{
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
top: 20%;
left: 50%;
z-index: 20;
display: block;
margin-left: -22px;
width: 44px;
height: 44px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 44px;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
background: url("color/img/color-icons.png") no-repeat;

-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.f-single a{text-decoration: none;}
.image-hover-overlay {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
}
.f-image .image-hover-overlay,.t-photo .image-hover-overlay {
z-index: 11;
background-color: #000!important;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.f-single:hover .image-hover-overlay,.t-element:hover .image-hover-overlay 
{
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=85);
opacity: .85;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.active .f-info {opacity: 1;}

.ca-container{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.ca-nav span {
width: 25px;
height: 38px;
background: transparent url(../img/f-next.png) no-repeat top left;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -19px;
left: -40px;
text-indent: -9000px;
opacity: 0.7;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 100;
}
.ca-nav span.ca-nav-next {
background-position: top right;
left: auto;
right: -40px;
}
.ca-wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
}
.ca-item{
position: relative;
float: left;
width: auto;
text-align: center;
}

.content{position: relative;}
.dark{background: #282828; padding-bottom: 85px;}

.f-single{
width: 467px;
float: left;
margin: 0 15px;
position: relative;
}
 .f-single:hover .f-image{
opacity: 1;
 }

.f-single:hover .f-info{
cursor: pointer;
opacity: 1;
background: #FF2C2C;
color: #fff;

-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}


.featured-carousel{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
.featured-list{overflow: auto;}
.nav-featured{
margin: 80px auto;
height: 57px;
width: 455px;
}
.nav-featured div{float: left; cursor: pointer;}
 .nav-featured .details-button {
margin-left:37%;
}

.prev-featured{
background: url("../img/f-prev.png") no-repeat #e1e1e1;
width: 30px;
height: 57px;
margin-right: 110px;
}
.prev-featured:hover{background-color: #000000;}
.next-featured{
background: url("../img/f-next.png") no-repeat #e1e1e1;
width: 30px;
height: 57px;
margin-left: 110px;
}
.next-featured:hover{background-color: #000000;}

.nav-featured .btn-featured{
color: #fff;
margin-top: 4px;
font-size: 14px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 400;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
background: #FF2C2C;
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 13px 25px 13px;
letter-spacing: 1px;

-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.nav-featured .btn-featured:hover{background: #000000;}
.btn-featured a{text-decoration: none; color: #fff;}

.title.one{ 
 color: #fff; 
 font-size: 37px; 
 letter-spacing: 5px; 
 padding: 120px 0 30px; 
 text-transform: uppercase;}
.title.two{color: #fff; font-size: 17px; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans- 
serif; width: 680px; margin: 50px auto;}
.f-info{
font-weight: 400;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
color: #ffffff;
background: #000000;
line-height: 30px;
padding: 40px 20px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.f-image{
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;

-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.light{background: #000; position: relative;}
.dark:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 30px solid #f7f7f7;
border-bottom: 0px solid transparent !important;
border-right: 30px solid transparent !important;
border-left: 30px solid transparent !important;
left: 50%;
bottom: -28px;
margin-left: -29px;
z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article class="content menu-top dark">
  <section class="featured-slider">
    <div class="ca-container">
      <div class="nav-featured">
        <div class="prev-featured">first carousel prev</div>
        <a href="#anchor3">
          <div class="btn-featured">Button</div>
        </a>
        <div class="next-featured">first carousel next</div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-carousel hideme dontHide">
        <div class="ca-wrapper">
          <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
            <div class="f-single">
              <a href="#" class="mfp-iframe">
                <div class="f-image">
                  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/7/71/Quebec_citadelles_200x200.png" alt='img'>
                  <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                  <span class="f-category"></span>
                  <div class="portfolio-meta">
                    <div>Text</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div>Watch Now</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-info">Text</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ca-item ca-item-2">
            <div class="f-single">
              <a href="#" class="mfp-iframe">
                <div class="f-image">
                  <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/assassinscreed/images/7/7d/200X200.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120929231337" alt='img'>
                  <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                  <span class="f-category"></span>
                  <div class="portfolio-meta">
                    <div>Text</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div>Watch Now</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-info">Text</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ca-item ca-item-3">
            <div class="f-single">
              <a href="#" class="mfp-iframe">
                <div class="f-image">
                  <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/cityville/images/5/58/Viral_basketballcomplex_basketball_200x200.png/revision/latest?cb=20130613014636" alt='img'>
                  <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                  <span class="f-category"></span>
                  <div class="portfolio-meta">
                    <div>Text</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div>Watch Now</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-info">Text</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ca-item ca-item-4">
            <div class="f-single">
              <a href="#" class="mfp-iframe">
                <div class="f-image">
                  <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/lego/images/1/16/Harrypottery5-7-200x200.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111021110949" alt='img'>
                  <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                  <span class="f-category"></span>
                  <div class="portfolio-meta">
                    <div>Text</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div>Watch Now</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-info">Text</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ca-item ca-item-5">
            <div class="f-single">
              <a href="#" class="mfp-iframe">
                <div class="f-image">
                  <img src="http://punkerslut.com/graphics-library-of-revolution-and-social-justice/anonymous-and-anonymous-movement/vectorportal---1/vectorportal---1__200x200.jpg" alt='img'>
                  <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                  <span class="f-category"></span>
                  <div class="portfolio-meta">
                    <div>Text</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div>Watch Now</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-info">Text</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ca-item ca-item-6">
            <div class="f-single">
              <a href="#" class="mfp-iframe">
                <div class="f-image">
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRKDkWdvfhgOAgyuq3TYy-7eUWP_LaQYv4g2kwLqtKmUPuFKkqX" alt='img'>
                  <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                  <span class="f-category"></span>
                  <div class="portfolio-meta">
                    <div>Text</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div>Watch Now</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-info">Text</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</article>



<article class="content menu-top dark">
  <section class="featured-slider">
    <div class="ca-container">
      <div class="nav-featured">
        <div class="prev-featured">second carousel prev</div>
        <a href="#anchor5">
          <div class="btn-featured">Button</div>
        </a>
        <div class="next-featured">second carousel next</div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-carousel hideme dontHide">
        <div class="ca-wrapper">
          <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
            <div class="f-single">
              <a href="img/image7.jpg">
                <div class="f-image">
                  <img src="http://chan.catiewayne.com/c/src/138578149239.png" alt='img'>
                  <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                  <span class="f-category"></span>
                  <div class="portfolio-meta">
                    <div>Text</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div>Text</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-info">Text</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ca-item ca-item-2">
            <div class="f-single">
              <a href="img/image9.jpg">
                <div class="f-image">
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEUHV4ecSVdfsq5zVsQtbCnQOg4HIZNsUghdDdsbu0hSxTDNycrQ" alt='img'>
                  <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                  <span class="f-category"></span>
                  <div class="portfolio-meta">
                    <div>Text</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div>Text</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-info">Text</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ca-item ca-item-3">
            <div class="f-single">
              <a href="img/image11.jpg">
                <div class="f-image">
                  <img src="http://www.mallvarna.com/files/rte/article33/batux-tux-g2-hd-200x200.png" alt='img'>
                  <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                  <span class="f-category"></span>
                  <div class="portfolio-meta">
                    <div>Text</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div>Text</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-info">Text</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ca-item ca-item-4">
            <div class="f-single">
              <a href="img/image13.jpg">
                <div class="f-image">
                  <img src="http://s2.dmcdn.net/KXh8h/200x200-CAR.jpg" alt='img'>
                  <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                  <span class="f-category"></span>
                  <div class="portfolio-meta">
                    <div>Text</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div>Text</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-info">Text</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ca-item ca-item-5">
            <div class="f-single">
              <a href="img/image15.jpg">
                <div class="f-image">
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR5A99ssb425kbuXfGX38qYSSDEgrvCr3IdaSXqZ7ZWOmqbRsSsNA" alt='img'>
                  <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                  <span class="f-category"></span>
                  <div class="portfolio-meta">
                    <div>Text</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div>Text</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-info">Text</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ca-item ca-item-6">
            <div class="f-single">
              <a href="img/image17.jpg">
                <div class="f-image">
                  <img src="https://serrescircuit.gr/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/male-200x200.jpg" alt='img'>
                  <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                  <span class="f-category"></span>
                  <div class="portfolio-meta">
                    <div>Text</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div>Text</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-info">Wales</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ca-item ca-item-7">
            <div class="f-single">
              <a href="img/image19.jpg">
                <div class="f-image">
                  <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/2548/f/2013/224/c/f/world_of_warcraft_200x200_by_dragoanasazi-d6hu54l.png" alt='img'>
                  <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                  <span class="f-category"></span>
                  <div class="portfolio-meta">
                    <div>Text</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div>Text</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-info">Text</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ca-item ca-item-8">
            <div class="f-single">
              <a href="img/image21.jpg">
                <div class="f-image">
                  <img src="http://www.atelierdecoz.fr/img/cms/thunderbird-logo-200x200.png" alt='img'>
                  <div class="image-hover-overlay"></div>
                  <span class="f-category"></span>
                  <div class="portfolio-meta">
                    <div>Text</div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div>Text</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="f-info">Text</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: This fixed everything:                                                                              
    $(".featured-slider").contentcarousel({
      sliderEasing: "swing"
    });                                                                                                                   
  Thank you!!!